# C# multiple threads and serial communication

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, serial-port

Today I come across some strange behavior. I have a serial device that I access using the `SerialPort` class. The main application has some timer that polls once every second the device for some status update. At a certain point I need to do some time consuming work and therefore not to block the GUI I used a `Backgroundworker`. The backgroundworker needs once to access the same serial device. Sometimes the access works sometimes not. Classical `mutli-thread` scenario. So I tried using a Mutex on the function that sends the new command to the serial device.

For the serial device I put everything together in it's own class. In this class I have a `sendCommand()` function thats write the command to the device and uses a `AutoResetEvent` and the `OnDataReceived` Event to wait for the answer. The function sendCommand blocks until the answer is received or a timeout occours. I then added the `Mutex` when entering the sendCommand and the `releaseMutex` on all possible exits. Still does not work.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks,
Tobias

Comment: releaseMutex? Working with C#? Just wrap the whole function inside a lock() statement?

Comment: Are you seeing an error message or does the application lock up waiting for the mutex to release?

Comment: Your device dont support duplex channel?

Comment: Can you post some code? Specifically the parts you are trying to synchronize?

Comment: The premise is very tricky.  Best done by push, not pull.  Run the code that processes the response when it is received.

Comment: msdn: "The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received". Also, DataReceived event is sometimes handled in a strange way by system: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e36193cd-a708-42b3-86b7-adff82b19e5e/how-does-serialport-handle-datareceived . Maybe that's the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I have an application that does this exact same thing -- what I did was I created a serial access class and, whenever I would call it (from either the GUI or one of my background threads) I would have the following:

```
private void myFunction(SerialClass myserialobject) {
  if (myserialobject == null)
    return;
  lock (myserialobject) {
    // code accessing the serial object
    // ...
    // when finished, close the lock statement
  }
}
```

I used this in both the main thread and any other threads requiring access.  It is blocking, but I believe it's a blocking statement.

Also, instead of using an event handler for `OnDataReceived` event I made my serial object perform a blocking read after any write, that way it prevented any data from being received in the wrong context.  I'm not sure how exactly your program is set up but you may want to consider doing that.  It works best if you know the number of bytes you expect to read upon writing to the port; that way you won't have to use `Sleep` to make sure all data was read.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do not know the number of bytes to receive. It's a ASCII type protocol where command are delimited by newline characters. After I received a empty line I must parse and check what I received before. It could be anything from zero datalines up to four. So I'm using `OnDataReeived` and write everything into a buffer until I receive an empty line. Then I set a `AutoResetEvent` to signal my `SendCommand` routine to process the data. The `SemdCommand` blocks until data are received or timeout occured.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is run the serial read/write thread in a loop, reading commands from a BlockingQueue with a timed wait.  If a serial request object is received within the timeout, the thread executes it, if the wait times out, the thread peforms a poll of the serial device.